# use case diagram for social tracking application

Tags: architecture, uml, use-case, diagrams

That is my first use case diagram. the mobile application have the listed functions as shown

in the image these functions are manipulated by a web serves i do not know wither that diagram

is right or needed to be changed.

[use case diagram http://convert.neevia.com/docs/d50489ff-e37e-4dd7-a2a7-5225b1b739a7/Use%20Case%20Model1.png](http://convert.neevia.com/docs/d50489ff-e37e-4dd7-a2a7-5225b1b739a7/Use%20Case%20Model1.png)

Comment: This is not a programming question, If you phrase you problem more descriptively you will probably find great answers there: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uml

Answer (score 1):

I think it's almost fine. Just remove the server and its connections as it's not a user interaction it's the system itself.

Comment: but all functions are validated by the web service

Comment: Use cases diagrams must be simple and only show the main tasks. A validation enters in a such granularity... You just need to represent the main tasks of the user interaction with the system.

Comment: @user2918388 Actors are humans or systems that are EXTERNAL to your target system. So, User and mobile are OK, but server with services are part of your system and belong to deployment and components diagram.

Comment: @Lucas - I think you could be right, so I removed the comment. You might want to expand your answer a bit since you seem to know the subject matter and the OP does not.